# How to solve Repeated column in Grails mapping for entity?

Tags: grails, mapping, grails-orm

I have this class:

```
class TFTire implements Serializable {
    TFTireProperty propertyMake
    TFTireProperty propertySize
```

And this mapping:

```
static mapping = {
    version false
    table 'TF_TIRE'
    id composite:['siteID','idRec'], generator: "assigned"
    columns {
        idRec column: 'IDRec'
        siteID column: 'SiteID'
        propertyMake {
            column name: "siteID", joinTable: true
            column name: "IFPropertyMake"
        }
        propertySize {
            column name: "SiteID", joinTable: true
            column name: "IFPropertySize"
        }
```

If I keep only one TFTireProperty, it works fine. But I need to refer to more two TFTireProperty objects. And the key is always siteID and IFPropertySomething.

With two of them I get this error:

```
Caused by MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.mdw360.TFTire column: SiteID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: why are you mapping propertyMake and propertySize into same column?

Comment: The database is already mapped like this... We are just maintaining this system. The TFTire Column has three different columns like IFPropertyMake IFPropertySize and IFPropertyType... They are the key to TFTireProperty, which primary key is siteID and IDRec that I need to join into TFTire...